# Can't start again ALM service after stop it

Tags: testing, hp-quality-center

I installed trial version of HP QC 11.0. After installation ALM service runs ok, I can use Site Administrator, create new user and project. But after stopping ALM service I can't start it again. In system event log I see error `The HP Application Lifecycle Management service terminated unexpectedly` after try of start.

**Application & web server**: JBoss (installed by default during installation of HP QC)
OS: Windows server 2008 SP2
Database server: MS SQL 2008 SP1

Comment: I don't think stackoverflow is best place for a question of this type. There are dozens possible reasons why this might be happening. A more suitable place would be to post this question in qc support forum. http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Quality-Center-Support-Forum/bd-p/sws-QC_SUP

Comment: Thanks for advise. I already was on hp support site and found the answer: the Path environement variable needs to be short, because it's used in .bat script for JBoss installation and too long script can not be executed. So, I made Path shorter on time of ALM installation and then returned it back.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with log on credentials. I went into the component services and changed the username/password and voila (stupid security team forcing updated passwords).

Running HP ALM 12.02, MS Server 2012 and Oracle on the back.